# subscribe to multiple kafka topics at runtime

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to create a Microservice with Java Quarkus to subscribe to multiple topics at runtime. The Service will read the topic form an API at regular interval (once a day) and update the topic to consume.

My problem is to create the Kafka dynamic subscriber. I tried with

**quarkus.kafka-streams**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Slf4j
public class KafkaTopology {

    @Inject
    IResourceFileService resourceFileService;

    @Produces
    public Topology buildTopology() {

        log.info("Start building topology - Read from file the topics");
        List<TopicData> data = resourceFileService.getTopics();
        List<String> topics = data.stream().map(single -> single.getTopic()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        log.info("Topic list is" + topics);
        builder.stream(topics, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())).peek((topic, value) ->{
            log.info("Peek " + topic + "Value: " + value);
        });

        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

and application.properties is

```
quarkus.kafka-streams.bootstrap-servers=xxxx
quarkus.kafka-streams.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
quarkus.kafka-streams.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
quarkus.kafka-streams.sasl.jaas-config=xxxx
```

Unfortunately I get the error

```
2023-03-24 12:34:22,086 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.str.int.met.ClientMetrics] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error while loading kafka-streams-version.properties: java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null

WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.con.ConsumerConfig] (Quarkus Main Thread) These configurations '[streams.metadata.max.age.ms, bootstrap-servers, streams.commit.interval.ms, sasl.jaas-config, streams.auto.offset.reset, streams.cache.max.bytes.buffering, application-id]' were supplied but are not used yet.
Exception in thread "pool-12-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing list of topics
```

But topics exists :(

**OLD and deprecated**
**quarkus.kafka-streams**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyTopology {

    // this list is Dynamic and comes from a Event bus
    List<String> topics = List.of("topicA", "topicB");
    @Produces
    public Topology buildTopology() {

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        for(String topic : topics){
            builder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .mapValues(v -> {
                    System.out.println("Topic message elaboration" + v);
                    return v;
                });
        }
        return builder.build();

    }
}
```

**org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer**

```
public class CustomKafkaConsumer implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {

    List<String> topics = List.of("topicA", "topicB");
    private Consumer<String, String> consumer;

    public void start() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "xx");
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "xx");
        props.put("sasl.jaas.config", "22");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        this.consumer.subscribe(topics, this);
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.consumer.close();
    }

    public void poll(Duration timeout) {
        this.consumer.poll(timeout).forEach(record -> {
            // Process the message
            System.out.println("TOPIC" + record.topic());
            System.out.println("VALUE" + record.value());
            System.out.println("KEY" + record.key());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

and cannot find a solution... where can I find documentation? Or where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Quarkus problem. `SteamsBuilder.stream` should not be used in a loop as you're effectively telling it to only use the last topic you've iterated over when the Topology is actually built and ran.

Pass the collection to the function directly

> where can I find documentation?

[The Javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#stream(java.util.Collection))?

---

You should also use peek or foreach to print data, not mapValues with no changes

---

> create the Kafka dynamic subscriber.

A static list is not "dynamic". You'll need extra code to stop and modify the topics used by the topology. More specifically, adding/removing from topics list will not cause them to be consumed automatically

Comment: Hi! Please may you share a simple piece of code? I am really lost and cannot find a solution

Comment: Unclear what you're looking for. As mentioned, builder.stream already accepts a list, so you do not need a loop. In other words, `builder.stream(topics)`. I don't use Quarkus, so don't know about other errors